# How to fix no space left on device error while creating a new react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm, create-react-app

I am creating new reactJs application, I am getting error as Error: `ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/public'`

I have tried setting max user watches by command as follows:

1. sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=16384
2. sudo apt-get autoremove
3. sudo apt-get autoclean
4. I have 400Gb available space on my device

#### Detailed error

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/public'
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1409:26)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1446:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:185:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/procmart-2/tushar/react/seasons/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:185:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! seasons@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the seasons@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/procmart-2/.npm/_logs/2019-03-28T10_11_08_644Z-debug.log
```

#### UPDATE:

The problem is solved after restarting my laptop. output of `df -h` after restating is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           383M  1.9M  381M   1% /run
/dev/sda8       443G  115G  306G  28% /
tmpfs           1.9G   44M  1.9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      7.5M  7.5M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/54
/dev/loop1      196M  196M     0 100% /snap/vlc/555
/dev/loop2      148M  148M     0 100% /snap/skype/66
/dev/loop5      203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/768
/dev/loop4      5.0M  5.0M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/50
/dev/loop8       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6405
/dev/loop6      203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/770
/dev/loop7       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop3       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6350
/dev/loop9      7.5M  7.5M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/58
tmpfs           383M   16K  382M   1% /run/user/122
tmpfs           383M   44K  382M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: what the output `df -h` ?

Comment: thanks for you reply thanh problem is solved after restarting i have updated my question